# Suggestions for dependent multivariate and multi-outputs model

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, model

I have multiple predictors (ram, cpu, I/O etc.) (depended!) and looking for a model with multivariate outputs (I am trying to predict the same input fields given partial inputs).
I have tried some models but cant find a model that will fit the data requirements.
For example, lasso regression does not fit because it does not have a multi input-output version. 
Decision Tree regression does not fit because my inputs are dependent.. 
any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Lasso has the option Family="mgaussian". You can handle multivariate outputs with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LASSO linear regression with multiple outputs (or with a multivariate output), simply writing $Y=X\beta+\varepsilon$ where $Y$ is a matrix such that each column of $Y$ corresponds to one output (or one coordinate of your multivariate output) and $\beta$ is a coefficient matrix whose columns correspond to coefficients giving the corresponding column of $Y$.

Or if you're in trouble with matrices, then simply fit one LASSO linear model per coordinate of your multivariate output.

Comment: all right! will try that